# Deriving an lumped element LC circuit as the limit of a resonant cavity mode

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-current, resonance, electrical-engineering

In principle, an LC circuit is just a degenerate limit of an electromagnetic cavity, where the frequency $\omega_0$ of the resonant mode is much lower than the inverse size of the cavity. As a result, LC circuits are usually treated in the magnetoquasistatic limit and the lumped element approximation, but there should be no problem treating them starting from the full Maxwell's equations. I've been trying to do this, but I can't quite get the results to match up.

The standard treatment of resonant cavities is as follows: write the electric and magnetic fields as
$$\mathbf{E} = e(t) \tilde{\mathbf{E}}, \quad \mathbf{B} = b(t) \tilde{\mathbf{B}} \tag{1}\label{1}$$
where the mode spatial profiles satisfy, in natural units,
$$\nabla \cdot \tilde{\mathbf{E}} = 0, \quad \nabla \times \tilde{\mathbf{E}} = \omega_0 \tilde{\mathbf{B}}, \quad \nabla \cdot \tilde{\mathbf{B}} = 0, \quad \nabla \times \tilde{\mathbf{B}} = \omega_0 \tilde{\mathbf{E}} + \tilde{\mathbf{J}} \tag{2}\label{2}$$
where $\tilde{\mathbf{J}}$ is the current profile on the conductor surfaces. For concreteness, let's normalize by
$$\int_V \tilde{\mathbf{E}}^2 = \int_V \tilde{\mathbf{B}}^2 = 1.$$
If we excite the cavity with a current $\mathbf{J}_a$, Maxwell's equations give the equations of motion
$$\dot{b} = - \omega_0 e, \quad \dot{e} = \omega_0 b - \int_V \mathbf{J}_a \cdot \tilde{\mathbf{E}} \tag{3}\label{3}.$$
This is all standard. Now let's consider an LC circuit with capacitance $C$ and inductance $L$. Its state is described by a charge $Q$ on the capacitor and a current $I$ through the inductor, and by definition,
$$\frac12 \int_V \mathbf{B}^2 = \frac12 LI^2, \quad \frac12 \int_V \mathbf{E}^2 = \frac12 \frac{Q^2}{C} \tag{4}\label{4}.$$
Comparing this to the expressions above, we have the correspondences
$$b = \sqrt{L} \, I, \quad e = Q/\sqrt{C}.$$
Substituting this into the equations of motion above and eliminating $C$ using $\omega_0 = 1/\sqrt{LC}$ gives
$$\dot{I} = - \omega_0^2 Q, \quad \dot{Q} = I - \omega_0 \sqrt{L} \int_V \mathbf{J}_a \cdot \tilde{\mathbf{E}} \tag{5}\label{5}$$
which is **wrong**. We actually want to get Kirchoff's loop rule plus the definition of current,
$$\dot{I} = - \omega_0^2 Q + \frac{\mathcal{E}}{L}, \quad \dot{Q} = I.$$
My results are close to right, but they seem to effectively have the roles of $I$ and $Q$ reversed, or equivalently the location of the driving term flipped!

I've searched through a bunch of physics and engineering textbooks, but none of them has anything like my derivation above; either they work only with Maxwell's equations or only with lumped elements. Linking the two treatments should be very straightforward, so I must have done something basic wrong. What's the problem?

Comment: I think you're taking too many shortcuts.  If you really wanted to do this using Maxwell's equations you'd need to model the inductor, the cap, their geometry, and that of the wiring between them _in detail_.  You could probably do exactly that with an FEA program, but I'm not sure that you'd gain any really earth-shattering insights.

Comment: @TimWescott I don't think so -- I would need to do that if I was interested in computing $L$ and $C$ to high precision. But I'm just trying to get from Maxwell's equations to Kirchoff's laws here. That has to be possible, or else all of electrical engineering would collapse.

Comment: @knzhou, there are numerous aspects of the equation you have written that I disagree with.
If we assume harmonic oscillations and express the field in terms of complex numbers, then $\pm j\omega$ should come into play, not the time derivative (dot). Why is there no complex number $j=\sqrt{-1}$ anywhere? I also don't understand why you are writing an equation that containes both the time derivative (dot) and $\omega$ at the same time.

Comment: @HEMMI The use of complex valued fields is just an electrical engineering convention. I’m intentionally using real fields to keep things as simple as possible for physicists. There are no $\omega$’s anywhere in my equations, there is only $\omega_0$, a constant representing the resonant frequency of the mode.

Comment: A cavity has an infinite number of Eigenmodes. A resonant LC circuit has, if you want, just one. I don't see where the reduction to (the lowest?) one Eigenmode happens. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you lead me through your thinking with more detail on how you got from Eq. 1 to 2 to 3? Also, what is $\mathbf J_a$, where is this current? If your cavity is two metal plates with magnetic wall around (a "capacitor") then in the lowest order mode $\mathbf E$ is perpendicular to the surface currents on the metal and $\mathbf J_a \cdot \mathbf E = 0$.

Comment: @hyportnex (1) to (2) is just using the definition of a normal mode with angular frequency $\omega_0$. (2) to (3) just comes from combining (1) and (2). $\mathbf{J}_a$ is any current I'm putting into the cavity to excite it. For example, suppose I have a tiny battery-powered radio transmitter inside the cavity. When I turn it on, there is a current $\mathbf{J}_a$ in its antenna. Or suppose the cavity has two little holes, through which electrons fly in and out (which is what happens in accelerator physics all the time).

Comment: @FlatterMann Every real system has an infinite number of eigenmodes, a typical LC circuit is nothing more than a cavity where one mode frequency is much lower than all the others. So I focus on that mode in this question. As for the equations I'm writing down, they all apply for all the modes, so there should be various mode subscripts everywhere, but I suppressed that since I'm only interested in the lowest frequency mode.

Comment: @knzhou Customarily we aren't treating an LC-circuit as a full 3d Maxwell problem, because then you are back to TimWescott's comment, except that it's much, much harder to solve the true high frequency behavior of a wire loop attached to a plate capacitor than e.g. a square cavity.

Comment: @FlatterMann Certainly. Iknow that what I'm asking for is totally useless in practice -- I'm just bothered that I can't quite get the correspondence to work out because it should work in principle.

Comment: "where $\mathbf {\tilde J}$ is the current profile on the conductor surfaces."

Comment: the correct identification is not $\int |\mathbf E|^2 = \tfrac{Q^2}{C}$ but $\int |\mathbf E|^2 = CV^2$ and then the problem disappears, you will get $\ddot I + I \propto \mathcal E$, as required. In other words, $\mathbf E$ is an intensive quantity, and should correspond to voltage, charge is extensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me use a slightly different notation and certainly not normalize so we can see the dimensional parameters.

Start with Maxwell's equations:

$$\nabla \times \mathbf H = \mathbf J +\epsilon_0 \dot {\mathbf E}$$
$$\nabla \times \mathbf E = -\mu_0 \mathbf {\dot H}$$

and let $\mathbf E = e(t) \mathbf {\tilde E }$ and $\mathbf H = h(t) \tilde {\mathbf H }$, then

$$ h(t)\nabla \times \tilde {\mathbf H} = \mathbf J +\epsilon_0 \dot {e}(t) \tilde {\mathbf E} \tag{1}$$

and
$$e(t)\nabla \times \mathbf {\tilde E} = -\mu_0 \dot h(t) \mathbf {\tilde H} \tag{2}$$
Multiply $(1)$ by $\tilde{\mathbf E}$ and $(2)$ by $\tilde {\mathbf H}$ and integrate, then over space

$$h(t)\int d\tau (\nabla \times \mathbf {\tilde H})\cdot \mathbf {\tilde E} \\= \int d\tau\mathbf J\cdot \mathbf {\tilde E} +\epsilon_0 \dot e(t) \int d\tau|\mathbf {\tilde E}|^2 $$
and
$$e(t)\int d\tau (\nabla \times \mathbf {\tilde E})\cdot \mathbf {\tilde H} \\= -\mu_0 \dot h(t) \int d\tau|\mathbf {\tilde H}|^2 \tag{4}$$

Normalize so that $\int d\tau|\mathbf {\tilde E}|^2=\int d\tau|\mathbf {\tilde H}|^2=1$
and denote the *geometric* integrals by $k_2=\int d\tau (\nabla \times \mathbf {\tilde E})\cdot \mathbf {\tilde H}$ and $k_1=\int d\tau (\nabla \times \mathbf {\tilde H})\cdot \mathbf {\tilde E}$ with $g= \int d\tau\mathbf J\cdot \mathbf {\tilde E} $ to get

$$k_1h(t)=g+\epsilon_0\dot e(t) \tag{5}$$
$$k_2e(t)=-\mu_0\dot h(t) \tag{6}$$
Equations $(5)$ and $(6)$ represent a parallel "LC" circuit driven by a *current* source $g$ in which
$$L=\frac{\mu_0}{k_1}\\ C=\frac{\epsilon_0}{k_2}\tag{7}$$
and the identification of the field amplitudes are $$I(t)=k_1h(t)\\V(t)=k_2e(t)\tag{8}$$

I think the problem lies in identifying the electric field amplitude with charge while having the magnetic field amplitude identified with charge rate, that is current. This would be a mistake analogous to use velocity and not momentum as the conjugate variable to position in analytical mechanics. The proper identification of electric field amplitude is with voltage.

---

Comment: I also think that we can consider this to be a closed a system and then we have $\int d\tau \rm{div }(\mathbf E \times \mathbf H) =0$ from which it will follow also that $k_1=k_2$ but I have to think about that more. With respect to your question it does not matter.

Comment: Sorry to come back to this so late, but I checked again and you're completely right!

Comment: Another way to explain the problem is that I identified the amplitude of the magnetic field $b$ with the current in the solenoid. But when you have some external driving current, it _also_ contributes to $b$, so the true current is $I \propto (b - b_{\mathrm{ext}})$. Adding this term recovers all the expected results.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see anything wrong with your derivation, only that you compared scenarios with incompatible "experimental details".

As you found out, the driving term is on the "wrong" (other) side. Since you drove your cavity with a modulated current, the driving term is on the equation side with $I$, not too surprising. Kirchhoff's loop rule, however, is about voltages, hence the driving term is on the $Q$ side. In other words: The location of the driving term is an artifact; inherent to the resonator dynamics are the relationships
$$\dot{I} = - \omega_0^2 Q , \quad \dot{Q} = I ,$$
and those you recovered properly.

You may consider re-doing your calculation with the cavity being excited by a modulated electric field. I think you'd be more satisfied.

Comment: Sorry to come back to this so late, but this makes sense to me! Now I need to figure out exactly what how to parametrize such a modulated electric field, in terms of external charges and currents...